How to recycle old logs for applications in Server. running out of space in server as we have lot of applications which have logs
How to recycle old logs for applications in Server. Right now running out of space in server as we have lot of applications which have logs.
manually deleted old logs so we can get more space in server. is there a better way to manage this?
